# Using RangetoHtml Function and Excel Won't Close after functions are done running

Tags: vba, excel, email

Basically I created a report and then send it via an email.  I use Ron B's function to paste the excel sheets into the body of the email.  What happens is excel doesn't destroy or close after the send email function is done.  When I end task on it and run it again it says that the remote machine or server doesn't exits.  This is probably because I am not explicitly defining the objects but I don't know how to between the two procedures.  I tried making the xlApp Public but that didn't work.  I even tried adding it to the rangetohtml function but at the point of where it says rng.copy it says there is an object that is required.  I tried adding xlApp.rng.copy or wb.rng.copy or ws.rng.copy. So i have the below where the range to html copies the rng.  That is added to a temp workbook and copied into the email.  It call from the one function over to the other and I can't figure out how to destroy the excel session when it is done.

```
Set rng = xlApp.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng = wb.Sheets(2).Range("A:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set rng2 = xlApp.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Now the range to html says RangetoHtml(rng as Range) then at the bottom it says
    rng.copy
Below that when you debug it after end tasking on excel it stops on this line:
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
I know you are supposed to put either XlApp.Workbooks.Add(1) but in the rangeto Html function it isn't declared as an object but it is in the function that it is calling from.  I don't know what to do next and how to fix the code.  I am posting both functions so you can see the code.  When the send email happens it brings up the email and pastes the excel sheet into the email but excel doesn't closed.

```
Public Function sendEmailorbetechprealert()
Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim Item As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim bfile As String
Dim Cell As Range

bfile = "S:\_Reports\Orbotech\Orbotech - Open Deliveries Pre-Alert\Orbotech - Open Deliveries Pre-Alert - "

MyFileName = bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

Set rng = xlApp.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng = wb.Sheets(2).Range("A:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set rng2 = xlApp.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng2 = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then

Set appOutLook = Nothing
Set Items = Nothing
End If

If rng2 Is Nothing Then
Set appOutLook = Nothing
Set Items = Nothing

Exit Function

End If

strPath = "S:\_Reports\Orbotech\Orbotech - Open Deliveries Pre-Alert\"      'Edit to your path
strFilter = "*.xls"
strFile = Dir(strPath & strFilter)

'For Each Cell In Columns("E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

If strFile <> "" Then

    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Items = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
    Set Item = Items.Add("IPM.Note.iCracked")

    With Item
          .To = ""
          '.CC = 
        ''.bcc = ""
          .Subject = "Orbotech Open Deliveries Report Pre-Alert"
          .htmlBody = "This is the Open Deliveries Report.  Please open the attachment. These lines are what have been inbound." & RangetoHTML(rng) & "This is what is still due" & RangetoHTML(rng2)
         .Attachments.Add (strPath & strFile)
        '.Send
       Item.Display    'Used during testing without sending (Comment out 
.Send if using this line)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = False
    wb.Save
    wb.CheckCompatibility = True
    DoEvents
    End With
        Else
    MsgBox "No file matching please re run Orbotech Report"
        Exit Function 'This line only required if more code past End If
End If
'Next Cell
DoEvents
On Error GoTo 0
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True

xlApp.Quit
Set rng = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Exit Function

End Function
```

Now in the htmlbody it calls the RangetoHtml(rng) to paste it in the email.  He is the rangetohtml function:

```
Public Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    'xlApp.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     fileName:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB


TempWB.CheckCompatibility = False
TempWB.Save
TempWB.CheckCompatibility = True
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False



'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile


Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Any help that anyone can provide it would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Also when I use the fully qualified information in the below statment the html doesn't paste into the email                                                         
        Set rng = xlApp.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set rng = wb.Sheets(2).ws.Range("A:U").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: The ws.Range("A:U").SpecialCellst adding the ws at the front and qualifying it doens't paste the right info into the email.

Comment: `Workbooks.Add` is not using the instance of the Excel Application that you created.  When using multiple `Application` objects, you should always fully qualify them so that you don't get problems with instances being left active after you are finished.  You should either pass `xlApp` as a parameter to your subroutine and then use `xlApp.Workbooks.Add` (or whatever you use as the parameter name), or create another instance within the subroutine.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what software are you running this code in?  You are creating an Excel Application object, so I assume it isn't Excel.  You are creating an Outlook Application object, so I assume it isn't Outlook.  Is it Word?

Comment: I am using access.  I basically export an excel sheet as a report and then use the rnagetohtml to publish the report via an email.  The problem with what you are saying is I already tried that.  I put xlapp.workbooks.add but right above it it says "Object Required" on the rng.copy  Everytime I qualify it it says that and I don't know how to get past it.  What do I put before rng.copy.  Excel.application doesn't work.  xlapp doesn't work nor does workbooks or worksheets.  I don't know how to declare the xlapp between the two functions

Comment: Can you post fixed code?

Comment: `rng` shouldn't need to be qualified.  (It actually can't be, because it is an object in your MSAccess VBA code.)  It already refers to a range in a `Sheet` object which has been defined to be a property of a `Workbook` object which has been set to refer to a workbook open in your `xlApp` Excel Application instance.

Comment: @YowE3K I deleted my answer.  Sorry.  I didn't know to accept yours.

Comment: I deleted my answer so you can post yours again.  I should have accepted it.